# How to dispaly div outside overflow-x area

Tags: css, saas

[image]

How can I display this samll action dialog box on the top of tbody overflow-x:auto. As you can see action dialog is appearing inisde the scroll area and I have to scroll to click on below actions.

```
    tbody {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 120px;
  }

  thead tr {
    display: block;
  }

  td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
  }
  th {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with purely CSS. My suggestion would be adding this dialog box dynamically with JS.

Comment: Can you please suggest how

Comment: Are you using any sort of framework or is this just vanilla JS?

Comment: I am using Angular 8