# Position absolute with horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

I am trying to add horizontal scrolling to a table that presents the data vertically (data columns) instead of the classic horizontal presentation (data rows).
Below is what I currently have.

[image: The table I am creating]

Since I have more and more data in that table I need to add horizontal scrolling, but only to the right part of the table. I want the left ("Value" columns) to stay fixed. I achieved that already but as soon as I add an `overflow-x: scroll` to the div that contains the right part of the table the head titles are disappearing. Now they are still where they are supposed to according to devtools (2nd screenshot, the head title is highlighted with the devtools) but they are no longer visible.

[image: The table with overflow-x: scroll and highlighting the label with the devtools]

Each column has `position: relative` and places its own head title as one of its children with `position: absolute` and the corresponding `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` values to achieve the desired result.

What I don't understand is why the title is no longer visible as soon as the `overflow-x: scroll` is specified.

The following styles are applied:

```css
.table-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    z-index: 10;
}

.table-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    position: relative;
}

.head-title {
    top: -95px;
    left: calc(50% + 26px);
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
    text-align: left;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Thanks a lot to anyone bringing new leads!

Comment: It appears that changing the `top` property to `0` brings the head title down over the data but it is now visible. Not what I want to achieve but it's a lead.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem and I cannot guess what your code looks like. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As a matter of fact, I just found out the answer to my problem. It is caused by the boundaries of the scrollable area. 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215180/how-to-dispaly-div-outside-overflow-x-area

Comment: And I'm sorry for not providing more code but I'm unfortunately not at liberty to disclose most of my code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my problem was caused by the boundaries created by the browser when handling overflow.
Overflow causes the browser to create sort of a box out of which it is not possible (it seems) to display some data.
I achieved the desired result by moving the padding from the parent div to both children div (left and right parts of the graph).

For anyone experiencing the same problem, here is the SO question that pointed me in the right direction: [How to dispaly div outside overflow-x area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215180/how-to-dispaly-div-outside-overflow-x-area)

Thanks to anyone who tried to help me in that regard.